# Process events in batches with event subscription model c#

Tags: events, observable, publish-subscribe

I have a dashboard which saves one or more events and a service which will get triggered upon receiving each event. Dashboard can be used by multiple users and save multiple events at the same time.

On the service side I subscribed for those events and processing each event in a new thread(using Task.Factory.startnew()).

Now that I want to queue up all the events and process them 5 at a time due to load issues.

As my OnNext() method will be called separately each time a single event is saved , I’m unable to queue up the received events.Is there any mechanism I can implement to achieve that ?

Tried setting maxdegreeparallelism but didn’t worked